# what information should be available in .sh file

Tags: java, maven, appium-android, bitbar

I'm new to BitBar and did a very basic setup looking at a videos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxTnmDHxG14) but actually not aware what content/code should be available in .sh file and all the prerequisites which are required.

Please help me to complete a setup.

---

I'm using Appium for Android device with Java language and Maven project

I ziped a complete project and uploaded it containing .sh file 
Also uploaded .apk file

Error message i received:

https://monosnap.com/file/oD9WQvmf08JvBqGRMjKZBVEnQJTA6i

Processing results 00:00.4
Server build has failed

Answer (score 1):

It is required to have run-tests.sh in the zip file top level. Make sure you zipped files, not the whole directory. It is a known issue and we are going to validate the files in the future and/or repackage them if needed, as well as provide more precise error messages.